# How to get the session numbers of every vncviewer background process and store them inside different variables

Tags: bash, shell, background-process, pid

I like to play with the bhyve virtual machines in FreeBSD a lot. As you probably know,sometime when the OS loaded by the virtual machine is halted,the process of the virtual machine is not killed. This is not a bug,but the developers say that it is like this to speed up the booting process of the virtual machines. Now,I would like to create a script to kill the "dead" virtual machines that are still listed when I do a "**ps ax | grep bhyve**",but that can't be used anymore. Let's take the example below :

```
mario@marietto:/home/marietto # ps ax | grep bhyve

13720  -  Is      0:00.00 bhyve: system.pwd (bhyve)
13721  -  Is      0:00.00 bhyve: system.grp (bhyve)
13831  -  Ss      0:00.00 bhyve: system.pwd (bhyve)
13832  -  Ss      0:00.00 bhyve: system.grp (bhyve)
13826  4  SC+     0:17.34 bhyve: vm2 (bhyve)
13715  1  IC+     1:00.55 bhyve: vm4 (bhyve)
13852  3  S+      0:00.00 grep bhyve
```

in this case I have two virtual machines called **vm2** and **vm4**,that became ghosts because the os inside of them has been halted. To be clear,I want to show you how is the script that I usually use to launch a bhyve vm :

```
bhyve -S -c sockets=2,cores=2,threads=2 -m 8G -w -H -A \
-s 0,hostbridge \
-s 1,nvme,/dev/nvd0,bootindex=1 \
-s 2,virtio-blk,/dev/$vmdisk4 \
-s 3,virtio-blk,/dev/$vmdisk8 \
-s 4,virtio-blk,/dev/$vmdisk11 \
-s 10,virtio-net,tap2 \
-s 11,virtio-9p,sharename=/ \
-s 12,hda,play=/dev/dsp,rec=/dev/dsp \
-s 29,fbuf,tcp=0.0.0.0:5902,w=1600,h=950 \
-s 30,xhci,tablet \
-s 31,lpc \
-l bootrom,/usr/local/share/uefi-firmware/BHYVE_BHF_CODE.fd \
vm2 < /dev/null & sleep 2 && vncviewer 0:2
```

now,since there isn't any easy method to know if a virtual machine is a ghost or if it is running,I've thought to a system like this :

```
mario@marietto:/home/marietto # ps ax | grep vnc

13841  4  S+      0:00.03 vncviewer 0:2
13727  1  S+      0:00.04 vncviewer 0:4
13854  3  S+      0:00.00 grep vnc
```

grepping the vncviewer session number is the most secure method to determine which virtual machine is really running because while a virtual machine is running really,I never close the vncviewer window but I minimize its window,and since I've associated the same number to the virtual machine and to the vncviewer session,I'm sure that the **vm2** and **vm4** are still running. When I will halt the **vm2** and the **vm4**,the corresponding vnc sessions should be closed for sure. Now,what I want to do is to create a script that as output is able to give me **2** and **4**,in that case. So,the script should assign the number **2** to the first variable and the number **4** to the second one :

```
$runvm1 = 2
$rvnvm2 = 4
```

Later I will complete the script like this :

```
bhyvectl --vm=$runvm1 --force-reset
bhyvectl --vm=$runvm1 --destroy
bhyvectl --vm=$runvm2 --force-reset
bhyvectl --vm=$runvm2 --destroy
```

because I want to reset and destroy all the ghost virtual machines that are still visible between the process listed with :

```
mario@marietto:/home/marietto # ps ax | grep bhyve
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get your values.

```
#!/bin/sh

BASE=`basename "$0" ".sh" `
TMP="/tmp/tmp.$$.${BASE}"

echo "
mario@marietto:/home/marietto # ps ax | grep bhyve

13720  -  Is      0:00.00 bhyve: system.pwd (bhyve)
13721  -  Is      0:00.00 bhyve: system.grp (bhyve)
13831  -  Ss      0:00.00 bhyve: system.pwd (bhyve)
13832  -  Ss      0:00.00 bhyve: system.grp (bhyve)
13826  4  SC+     0:17.34 bhyve: vm2 (bhyve)
13715  1  IC+     1:00.55 bhyve: vm4 (bhyve)
13799  8  IC+     1:00.55 bhyve: abc_vm4 (bhyve)
13852  3  S+      0:00.00 grep bhyve
" >${TMP}.testinput

cat "${TMP}.testinput" | grep '(bhyve)' |
    awk '{
        if( $6 ~ /^vm/ ){
            id=substr( $6, 3 ) ;
            printf("%s|%s|%s\n", id, $6, $1 ) ;
        } ;
    ### Sample output:
    ### 2|vm2|13826
    ### 4|vm4|13715
    }' |
    awk -F \| 'BEGIN{ indx=0 ; }{
        indx++
        printf("runvm"indx" = %s\n", $1 ) ;
    ### Sample output:
    ### runvm1 = 2
    ### runvm2 = 4
    }'
```